# PHP - Get exact iOS version from User-Agent

Tags: php, ios, regex, user-agent

I'd like to get the exact iOS version in PHP from the User-Agent. I am well aware of the possibilities with faking user-agents, but in my case, it isn't an issue.

An normal iPhone User-Agent String looks like this:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_2_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.4.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15C153 Safari/604.1
```

How can I extract the OS version from this? In this case it is "11_2_1". I got to be able to pull it from iPhone, iPad and iPod user-agents. It also can be X_X instead of X_X_X.

So far I got this:

```
<?php
$version = preg_match('(iPad|iPhone|iphone|iPod).*?(OS |os |OS\_)(\d+
((_|\.)\d)?((_|\.)\d)?)', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
echo $version;
?>
```

However, visiting it from an iPhone shows a blank page. Can someone help me please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `i(?:phone|pad|pod) os ([\d_]+)` or `i(?:phone|pad|pod) os \K[\d_]+` or `ip(?:hone|[ao]d) os \K[\d_]+`?

Comment: Note `preg_match()` returns false on error, which won't echo. You might want `var_dump()` instead.

Comment: @AlexHowansky returns bool(false);

Comment: @ctwheels Sorry, I am kind of lost here.. not too experienced.

Comment: @Johnny Give me a moment to post an answer

Comment: Until you get a grasp on regex, https://regexr.com/ can be very useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Code

There are multiple regular expressions that you can perform to get the OS version. The regex below is likely the fastest:

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/zR8nnO/2)

```
ip(?:hone|[ao]d) os \K[\d_]+
```

**Note**: These regexes all use the `i` flag.

Other variations may also be used such as:

```
i(?:phone|pad|pod) os \K[\d_]+
i(?:phone|pad|pod) os ([\d_]+)
```

#### Usage

[See code in use here](https://ideone.com/igyK6t)

```
<?php

$re = '/ip(?:hone|[ao]d) os \K[\d_]+/i';
$str = 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_2_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.4.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15C153 Safari/604.1';
preg_match($re, $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 0);
var_dump($matches);
```

**Note**: To separate each version part in the result you can use the following line [as shown here](https://ideone.com/z50Zo5):

```
var_dump(explode("_", $matches[0][0]));
```

#### Usage - With OP's Code

```
<?php

$re = '/ip(?:hone|[ao]d) os \K[\d_]+/i';
preg_match($re, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 0);
var_dump($matches);
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_2_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.4.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15C153 Safari/604.1
```

#### Output

Outputting the match:

```
11_2_1
```

Outputing the match with [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) on `_` (seen in the note under the first **Usage** section):

```
11
2
1
```

---

### Explanation

- `ip` Match this literally
- `(?:hone|[ao]d)` Match either of the following

  - `hone` Match this literally (makes `iphone`)
  - `[ao]d` Match either `a` or `o` followed by `d` (makes `ipad` or `ipod`)
- Match a literal space character
- `os` Match this literally
- Match a literal space character. I noticed the OP also had `OS\_`, which makes me think there may be a possibility for an underscore character here. If that's the case [this can be changed to `[ _]` instead](https://regex101.com/r/zR8nnO/3).
- `\K` Resets the starting point of the match. Any previously consumed characters are excluded from the final match
- `[\d_]+` Match one or more of any digit or underscore characters

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation - works absolutely fine!

Comment: @Johnny you're very welcome! Let me know if you need clarification on anything :)

Answer (score 2):

This should do the job:

```
$version = preg_match("/OS ((\d+_?){2,3})/i", $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], $matches);
print_r(str_replace("_",".",$matches[1]));
```

Comment: This returns only "11", while the target browser is 11_2_1.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a User-Agent parser or even create your own. [Here](https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/parse/#parse-useragent) you have an example, Also I found this php project [PhpUserAgent](https://github.com/donatj/PhpUserAgent), which should be very simple to use:

```
$result = parse_user_agent($ua);
```

then you can extract the `version` from that object.

This [`user-agent-parser`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/user-agent-parser) for javascript also works very well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this: `"/(i(?:phone|pad|pod)) OS (\d+_\d+_\d+)/i"`.

Comment: Yeah, forgot to add the `i` in the end for case insensitive match. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't work with `Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 5_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 ...`

Comment: @TommasoBelluzzo This case is a bit confusing as it doesn't formatted as the exampled given. After `CPU` I assume the presence of of a string like `iphone`. It seem as a trick case which eLRuLL didn't mention. And it will not match the answer ctwheels gave.